# Chose network connection through xrdp

Tags: openvpn, networkmanager, lubuntu, xrdp

I've setup XRDP on a Lubuntu box, but it does not give me an option to choose which wireless network to connect to, nor can I connect to a VPN server like you can through the normal GUI. It uses whatever settings were already selected through the normal GUI.

Is there a way to select this through xrdp? Or can I configure the gui on xrdp to look more like the default gui?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently, you can't choose network settings when still logged in locally on the box.  I logged out and then I was able to select networks on the RDP session.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on which OS you are using, there's a good chance the problem is with `polkit`.  On Ubuntu, if you create the file `[RuleName].pkla` in `/etc/polkit-1/localauthority/50-local.d/`, with rule text to allow network changes, this will begin to work.  I caution that I think this also causes some vulnerability, so I would only recommend this to use on an otherwise isolated or well protected machine.

Step by step example:

```
user@pc:~$ su -
#Don't have to do this, but you will need sudo for writing in the folder/making the rule.  Use whatever method you want.

root@pc:~$ cd /etc/polkit-1/localauthority/50-local.d/
root@pc:/etc/polkit-1/localauthority/50-local.d/$ touch WifixRDPrule.pkla
#Make the rule file in the right folder

root@pc:/etc/polkit-1/localauthority/50-local.d/$vim WifixRDPrule.pkla
```

Now that you're in `VIM` or whatever texteditor you want to use (will need superuser access), add the following rule:

```
[Allow Wifi Scan]
Identity=unix-user:*
Action=org.freedesktop.NetworkManager.wifi.scan;org.freedesktop.NetworkManager.enable-disable-wifi;org.freedesktop.NetworkManager.settings.modify.own;org.freedesktop.NetworkManager.settings.modify.system;org.freedesktop.NetworkManager.network-control
ResultAny=yes
ResultInactive=yes
ResultActive=yes
```

[Reference](https://c-nergy.be/blog/?p=16310).  This allowed us to connect and change networks.